# Постраничная навигация пути реализации

Tags: html

Коллеги, добрый день, вопрос к фронт-программистам. Уважаемые фронтовики подскажите пожалуйста новичку исходя из вашего опыта как лучше реализовать постраничную навигацию, если примерно планируется создание 30-34 страниц по 12-20 Мбайт контента на страницу.

Comment: я б это на фронте не делал бы... лучше и правильнее это делать на стороне сервера...

Comment: Если задача "бить большой контент на кусочки", то бить его надо на сервере, сервер должен предоставлять возможность запросить отдельный кусок, а клиент соответственно запрашивать кусок и показывать.  Если грузить на клиент сразу все, то есть шанс что все будет очень мееееееееедлееееееееннооооооо